# Server ignores cUrl code lines php

Tags: php, curl

iam using that php code in the localhost and working fine

```
$ch = curl_init($src);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
```

when i move it to the remote server the script ignores that code

and doesn't give me  a result (still giving me the original url )

note: i use cURL here to give me the true url after redirect

Comment: Is there anything in the `php error log` or the `apache logs`. Does the remote server have the curl extension enabled?

Comment: yeah the cUrl is enabled and i have no access to those logs :(

Comment: thank you problem solved it was the host restricting outgoing connections :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is some difference in the configuration of the remote server.

phpinfo();

Shows the configuration of php and of the curl module